# serial monitor error/crash

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, embedded, atmel

[image: serial monitor]

After typing C, microcontroller responds with #
Next, I type k, microcontroller responds with #INFO: TWI master enabled
Next, I type !, microcontroller responds with C

after typing in the next command "EG", the screen gives that error. i have tried screen package on linux and it has the same issue.

```
switch (command){
        case 'E': //Experiment options
            experiment_handler(getchar());
            break;

        case 'S': //Settings options
            settings_handler(getchar());
            break;

        case 'T': ;
            uint16_t tcs_data[] = {0,0,0,0};
            if (settings.settings.tcs_enabled == 0){
                printf("T-1.-1.-1.-1\n");
            }
            else {
                tcs_readvalues(tcs_data);
                printf("#INFO: TCS—%u %u %u %u\n", tcs_data[0], tcs_data[1], tcs_data[2], tcs_data[3]);
                printf("T%u.%u.%u.%u\n", tcs_data[0], tcs_data[1], tcs_data[2], tcs_data[3]);
            }
            break;

        case 'V': //check version
            #define STRING2(x) #x
            #define STRING(x) STRING2(x)
            #pragma message "GIT_COMMIT = " STRING(GIT_COMMIT)
            printf("V%u.%u.%u-%s\n", BOARD_VER_MAJOR, BOARD_VER_MINOR, BOARD_VER_MICRO, GIT_COMMIT);
            break;

        default:
            printf("#ERR: Command %c not recognized\n", command);
            return;
    }
    printf("no\n");
    return;
}

int main(void){

    board_init();
    pot_init();
    pmic_init();

    irq_initialize_vectors();
    cpu_irq_enable();
    sleepmgr_init();
    sysclk_init(); //Disables ALL peripheral clocks D:
    rtc_init();
    sysclk_enable_module(SYSCLK_PORT_GEN, SYSCLK_EVSYS);

    pmic_set_scheduling(PMIC_SCH_ROUND_ROBIN);

    delay_ms(500);

    stdio_usb_init();
    stdio_usb_enable();

    ads1255_init_pins();
    ads1255_init_module();

    PORTD.INT0MASK = PIN5_bm;
    PORTD.INT1MASK = PIN5_bm;
    PORTD.INTCTRL = PORT_INT0LVL_OFF_gc | PORT_INT1LVL_OFF_gc;

    max5443_init_pins();
    max5443_init_module();

    ads1255_wakeup();
    ads1255_rdatac();
    ads1255_standby();

    ads1255_setup(ADS_BUFF_ON,ADS_DR_60,ADS_PGA_2);

    autogain_enable = 0;
    g_gain = POT_GAIN_30k;
    pot_set_gain();

    settings_read_eeprom();

    wdt_set_timeout_period(WDT_TIMEOUT_PERIOD_8KCLK); // 8 secs

    //  Wait for application connection - Get 'c', reply '#', get 'k'
    while(1){
        while(getchar() != 'c');
        putchar('#');
        while(getchar() != 'k');
        printf("\n\r");
        break;
    }

    tcs_init();
    wdt_enable();

    program_loop:
        while(getchar() != '!');
        printf ("C\n");
        command_handler(getchar());
        wdt_reset();
    goto program_loop;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this is a problem of **electrical** engineering.

Comment: which text character causes the issue? ... do any other text characters cause the same failure?

Comment: text character 'EG'      ps: 'G' is from another source code in the same firmware as the main.c program i uploaded above

Comment: Can you describe the serial connection is more detail? Is via USB? Does it involve a dedicated USB-to-UART chip or is it done in software in the microcontroller? The serial protocol does not have any features to terminate a connection. So it's more likely that the underlying USB connection was terminated, either due to a power issue or due to a sofware crash if the USB to UART conversion is done in software.

Comment: Most likely your `experiment_handler` function crashed or blocked the microcontroller. Therefore, the USB connection becomes unresponsive and the PC terminated the USB connection (incl. the serial connection).

Comment: @codo it is done over software in the microcontroller. it definitely isn't a power issue. what could be the cause of a software crash

Comment: @codo what changes should i make in the experiment_handler function

Comment: Show the code of `experiment_handler`. That would really help us help you. It can be many things: invalid memory access triggering an exception, invalid memory access corrupting the USB data structures, long running code that triggers the watchdog etc.

Comment: i was able to solve the issue by eliminating the watchdog but the challenge am having now is that whenever i send the command EG, the microcontroller doesn't respond with what its meant to respond with (i.e  30k ) until i send ! again

Comment: what can i do to make it respond to the EG command without sending !

Answer (score 1):

The MCU hangs (or resets due to not handling the watchdog on time), so it stops handling the USB protocol stack, and PC thinks the cable is detached so USB serial port stops existing. You have a problem in the MCU firmware.